# Python cannot find modules 'official.legacy' and 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to install and run Tensorflow on my Windows computer without using the GPU for now, but even after having followed all the steps in the [Tensorflow Api Detection API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) with no eror whatsoever but I still cannot run the test script.

Whenever I do I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 36, in <module>
from official.legacy.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.legacy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 70, in <module>
from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 38, in <module>
from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 37, in <module>
from official.vision.image_classification import preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\preprocessing.py", line 25, in <module>
from official.vision.image_classification import augment
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\augment.py", line 31, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as image_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'
```

I found nothing that could help me online, I tried adding the /models folder to PYTHONPATH, I installed all the required packages from the requirements.txt but the error remained the same. I'm not sure what's the problem here since I do have Tensorflow 2.12.0 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faound the cause of the problem. I apprentl was running my command in a broken installation of the object_detection folder, meaning it was just that and had all the superior folders missing. Changing folder to my new clean installation solved the problem completely

Answer (score 0):

You should install the module `tf-models-official`:

```
pip install tf-models-official
```

or update its version if you already have it installed.

Comment: I already installed them from the repository, in fact if I do run the pip command it just tells me "Requirement already satisfied" for all of them

Comment: which version do you have? (pip show tf-models-official)

Comment: The version 2.5.1

Comment: try to update it with a newer version such as `pip install tf-models-official==2.8.0`

Comment: I'm getting alot of "requirement already satisfied" and some error about some of the model not having a version 2.8.0

Comment: Just as a test, try to run 'pip install --no-dependencies tf-models-official' to force to install it without dependencies and to see if your error goes away or not.

Comment: Still there, I don't think that's the problem to be honest

Comment: If I try and run some other code that uses a custom model it gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.models'`

Comment: This last error seems more related to the fact you don't have models inside the object_detection directory. Does it contain any models?

Comment: I was, in fact, running the script in an older folder that wass missing a ton of libraries